# Can i link remote jar's and remote source code using Intellij community edition

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, remote-server

I use Intellij to develop Java code. My current intellij is installed on a host that i access using VNC Viewer (Introduces lag while working). I still put up with this as third party jars libraries and the source code is present on the host on which intellij is installed.
Is it possible for me to install Intellij on one machine and create a project wherein i can choose third party jar libraries to be on a different host and also the Source code to be on a remote host?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount (on *nix) or map network drive (windows) the folders with sources/libraries that are on the remote machine, then use local setup of IntelliJ IDEA with these folders as if they were on the same local machine.